# Karate: JSON is converted to string ([object Object]) when matching

Tags: karate

I'm trying to match the response of an API with a schema. I have the following setup.

Here is the feature file:

```
Feature: As a user, I would like to test APIs of member modules.

  Background:
    * def DIR_PATH = 'data/users/'
    * def signup_request_helpers = read(<path_to_js_file>)
    * def signup_response_helpers = read(<path_to_js_file>)
    * def request_data = signup_request_data()

  Scenario: Test signup of user
    Given url my_url
    And request request_data
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    Then match response == signup_response_schema
```

Here is the JS file that holds the response schema

```
var signup_response_schema = {
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfully signed up.",
    "data": {
        "user": user_schema,
        "confirmation_url": "#string",
        "token": "#string",
        "role": "#array"
    }
};
```

The problem is that karate seems to be converting the response schema into a string. This is the error message that I get:

```
actual: {<response>}, expected: [object Object]
```

Please note that I can match individual string fields fine. The problem only occurs when I try to match objects. Also, I have tried printing the schema and the variable seems to be holding the correct value which is the schema object.

I've tried the following:

- Convert the schema into a string and then a JSON using the library's directives. This doesn't verify the schema
- Convert directly to json which still renders the schema as `[object Object]`

**NOTE:** I'm running Karate on docker if that makes any difference. Following is the command that I use in my docker-compose file:

`java -jar  -Dkarate.config.dir=/app /app/karate-0.9.1.jar -T 5 path_to_file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here wasn't of JS evaluation. The variable `signup_response_schema` holds the value that I assigned to it in the JS file.

The problem was with the actual matching of the schema because one of the keys was missing in the actual response. Karate usually throws specific error messages indicating which keys were missing but for some reason, this isn't the case here.

Comment: I don't understand but I guess something works for you. do consider following the process since if there is an opportunity to improve the error message we can take a look - else no worries

Answer (score 0):

JS in Karate is not *that* seamless. This will work:

```
var temp = {
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfully signed up.",
    "data": {
        "user": user_schema,
        "confirmation_url": "#string",
        "token": "#string",
        "role": "#array"
    }
};
karate.set('signup_response_schema', temp);
```

Normally in Karate `*.js` files start with `function` and contain a single function block. And the result of reading (evaluating) that block is assigned to a Karate variable using `def`. But the recommended option for you is this, where you just have a JSON in the file, and the extension matters:

```
Then match response == read('signup_response_schema.json')
```

Note that `read()` will also evaluate embedded expressions, which can be useful. Although the JSON is not expected to be strictly well-formed, it is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, appreciate it. Please note that this wasn't the issue and the js was being evaluated fine. The issue was that there was a mismatch of a single key. Karate threw this generic error instead of pointing out the missing key. Is this expected behavior? I've added the command I used in docker-compose to run the tests in the question body.

Comment: @SaadAleem sorry, I don't think you have understood my answer. can you just do this a) rename the file to `signup_response_schema.json` b) make sure the contents are pure JSON. c) use the `match` line I suggested - else sorry I can't help, follow this process if you are still stuck: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue